# How to remove everything apart from math signs java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which is a maths sum. e.g. `3+5*5/2` etc
I want to get one string array that contains the numbers and another array that contains the operations.

I have get the numbers by itself but I can't get the operations.

This is what I have so far:

```
String extractingIntegers = "4+5*9/8-6";
String[] operationsInStringformat = extractingIntegers.split("[^0-9]");
String[] numbersInStringformat = extractingIntegers.split("\\D");
```

The `\\D` works but not the `[^0-9]`

Comment: Why not just *match*  them with `[-*+/]`? Why do you want to *split*?

Comment: Well, have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/Ca5B0U). Looks like it matches all there needs to be matched.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ:Your answer was downvoted because of `String[] operationsInStringformat = extractingIntegers.split("[!0-9]");`

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of \D is \d

```
String extractingIntegers = "4+5*9/8-6";
String[] operationsInStringformat = extractingIntegers.split("\\d");
String[] numbersInStringformat = extractingIntegers.split("\\D");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the ^ in the below line
String[] operationsInStringformat = extractingIntegers.split("[0-9]+");
Also include + to handle numbers with more than 1 digit.